# Exportar um .xlsx com Java

Tags: java, microsoft-excel

Estou tentando exportar uma planilha com Java, especificamente um arquivo `.xlsx`, mas não estou conseguindo.

Estou fazendo da seguinte maneira e está funcionando, mas só funciona colocando a extensão `.xls`:

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
String PathTillProject = System.getProperty("user.dir");
FileOutputStream fileOut = null;

fileOut = new FileOutputStream(PathTillProject + "/src/Export.xls");
workbook.write(fileOut);
```

Se eu colocar no `fileOut` a extensão `.xlsx`, na hora de abrir o arquivo, fala que está a extensão do arquivo não é válida.

Estou importando o seguinte arquivo:

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
```

O que devo fazer para conseguir exportar com outra extensão?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para criar uma planilha Excel, no formato `.xlsx`, é necessário utilizar com o import do `Apache POI-XSSF/SXSSF`. o `HSSF` somente trabalha com planilhas `.xls`.

Pode converter o código já feito, para esse código:

```
//criar uma planilha
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();

//pegar o diretório do usuário e criar um arquivo com o determinado nome
String PathTillProject = System.getProperty("user.dir");
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(PathTillProject + "/src/Export.xls");

//criar várias abas
XSSFSheet abaPrimaria = wb.createSheet("ABA 1");
XSSFSheet abaSecundaria = wb.createSheet("ABA 2");

//criar linhas (passar o nome da aba onde deseja criar)
XSSFRow primeiraLinha = abaPrimaria.createRow(0);
XSSFRow segundaLinha = abaPrimaria.createRow(0);

//criar uma célula em uma linha (passar o nome da linha onde deseja criar)
XSSFCell primeiraCelulaColuna = primeiraLinha.createCell(0);
XSSFCell segundaCelulaColuna = primeiraLinha.createCell(1);

//escrever tudo o que foi feito no arquivo
wb.write(fileOut);

//fecha a escrita de dados nessa planilha
wb.close();
```

Basicamente, ele segue os mesmos parâmetros da utilização do `HSSF`, só muda a chamada e o import desse `.jar`.

Answer (score 0):

Para xlsx você deve usar XSSFWorkbook   ao invés de HSSFWorkbook. exemplo:

```
    InputStream ExcelFileToRead = new FileInputStream("C:/Test.xlsx");
    XSSFWorkbook  wb = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFileToRead);

    XSSFWorkbook teste = new XSSFWorkbook();
```

Comment: mas, nesse caso, não é para pegar um arquivo `.xlsx` para ler? testei aqui e não funcionou, quero gerar um arquivo `.xlsx`.

Answer (score -2):

Cara eu tinha olhado a lib toda, e não tava achando a classe XSSFWorkbook, ai depois de pesquisar aqui vi que o B.O era a dependência que havia adicionado no meu pom.xml

Importa esse carinha aqui no teu projeto e substitui as classes HSSF por XSSF que tu vai conseguir exportar .xlsx

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: A pergunta não diz que o usuário está usando o Mavem.

Comment: Saquei, o objetivo de ter adicionado o comentário acima utilizando o MAVEN foi apenas para agregar caso alguém em 2022 como eu tivesse tentando gerar uma planilha em xlsx e deparasse com a situação pontuada nesse tópico do fórum

Comment: O Stack Overflow em Português [não é um fórum](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2068/137387). Nós [somos um site de pergunta e respostas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/137387) práticas, detalhadas e sem distrações, nosso objetivo é obter respostas diretas ao problema apresentado em cada página. Para mais informações leia [answer]. [FAQ da comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/699/137387) e [help]. Para encontrar questões específica sobre o Mavem procure na tag [tag:mavem].

Comment: A resposta do @MaxwellJ.Alves é útil e a informação está correta para a pergunta feita! Se acharam incompleta ou insuficiente, bastaria propor uma edição (já fiz) em vez de negativar. Por exemplo, bastaria adicionar a frase "As classes que exportam XLSX e estão localizadas na biblioteca abaixo e têm o nome iniciado com XSSF (em vez de HSSF)". Mesmo que a pessoa não estivesse utilizando Maven, a informação continua sendo útil por apontar para a biblioteca poi-ooxml, o que pode ser adaptado para qualquer estrutura de projeto. E Maven se escreve com N no final, esse link para a tag está errado.